# Select several layers by name using an expression

Tags: pyqgis, layers, select

I'm am new to using PyQGIS and this question has been answered in various forms already, however not specifically the way I need it; I have a big QGIS project with several layers with similar, but not the same names (e.g. names containing certain keywords like "nationalpark", "flooding zone" etc.), and I want to apply Styles to all layers with names containing certain keywords, e.g. "nationalpark". I found out that I can select layers using e.g.

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my layer name')
```

but how can I select layers by non-specific names, containing certain keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python's [in operator](https://realpython.com/python-in-operator/#strings) to retrieve the layers in your project whose names contain a keyword/words.

E.g.

```py
key_word = "flooding zone"

layers = [lyr for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if key_word in lyr.name()]

print(layers)

for lyr in layers:
    # Do something with layer...
    lyr.loadNamedStyle('path/to/style.qml')
```

The [mapLayers()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#aea8f57f53a7b973d75cad88bd8abbebc) method of `QgsProject` returns a dictionary, so we use Python's `values()` method to access the `QgsMapLayer` objects.